# Cannot connect to localhost on port 4430

Tags: centos, nginx, ssl, port-forwarding, reverse-proxy

I am running `vagrant` from a `virtual box` with `CentOS` and `Nginx` installed. I've created a reverse tunnel from the vagrant box to a remote server but when I am trying to connect to my localhost on port 4430 I keep getting the below error when I run the command:

```
curl -v 'https://localhost:4430'

* About to connect() to localhost port 4430 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I have been trying to load the site in the browser but Chrome throws an error too.

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What I am trying to do is create a reverse tunnel which seems to work fine in that I can connect to a remote machine and create the tunnel but I cannot browse using the desired (reversed port) on my local machine.

Here's my tunnel script:

```
ssh -v -R 4430:localhost:443 user@remote-domain.com -N
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

I can connect using port 443 but not 4430!

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Running the following command gives the following output

```
ssh -v -R 4430:localhost-domain:443 ec2-user@vm.domain.com -N

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to vm.domain.com [54.149.189.155] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'vm.domain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:4430 forwarded to remote address localhost-domain:443
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 4430.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 4430.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

I'm thinking `LOCALHOST:4430` should be the hostname of the vagrant box? E.g `local-domain:4430`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `-g` option, because otherwise the remote port will only be listening on `localhost`, meaning that any other host than the remote `localhost` won't be able to connect to it.

With `-g` it listens to `0.0.0.0`, which means it's available on all interfaces and not only `localhost`.

As `ssh(1)` says the `g` option "Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.  If used on a multiplexed connection, then this option must be specified on the master process."

You also mention that you've created this tunnel in a vagrant box. So this `curl` which your showing is also inside the vagrant box, right? Otherwise, if you run the `curl` on the host system and not inside the vagrant box that wouldn't work. If you want to connect to the tunnel from the host system (not inside the vagrant box) you'd have to connect to the IP of the vagrant box instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hi @mauro.stettler I've added the `-g` flag to the tunnel script but still I can browse on port `4430` I also get the same output as above...

Comment: So where does the curl run, inside the vagrant or on the base host?

Comment: I run it inside the `vagrant ssh`

Comment: But you're using `-R` to create a reverse tunnel, shouldn't that be `-L` to create a forward tunnel?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to create a reverse tunnel.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand that correctly. The `ssh` command runs inside a vagrant box, then you want to connect through that tunnel from inside the vagrant box, correct? In this case what you need is a forward tunnel and not a reverse tunnel.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure I understand.  You ssh with that command line from a client machine to a server?  Then on the server you run the curl command to port 4430?

That should work.  If it doesn't then log into the server and check if port 4430 is listening via

```
netatat -tnl | grep 4430
```

Possibly sshd is configured to not allow port forwarding.

If you want to run curl on the client to connect to localhost:4430 in order to connect to the server's port 443 then you should use -L instead of -R.

Comment: Hi, I have the port forwarding setup correctly. However, it is listening on localhost:4430 or 127.0.0.1:4430 when I need it to use my configured IP and hostname. I have my vagrant box running on 192.168.56.0 with the hostname vm.domain.com so what I need to do is have vm.domain.com:4430 instead of localhost:4430 (see edit)